# magento soap api v2 - get Customer with newsletter subscription

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am trying to retrieve all customers from my magento shop, but only those who activated the newsletter subscription in their account.

Problem: I cant figure out how to filter this attribute ("newsletter", is there one?).

I got:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$params = array(
    'sessionId' => $session_id,
    'filters' => null
);
$allCustomers = $proxy->customerCustomerList($params);
```

This returns ALL customers.
Any ideas how to filter this by newsletter-subscription?

Answer (score 4):

Newsletter subscriptions are stored is a separate module. `Mage_Newsletter`.
There doesn't appear to be any API coverage for this module, however if you take a quick peak at the `newsletter_subscriber` database table you'll see subscribers that are also customers have a foreign key relating them.

I'd probably look at adding an attribute to `Mage_Customer` that holds subscription status, adding an observer to the subscribe and unsubscribe events to update it.

I'd then look to add this attribute to the `Mage_Customer` API so I can filter by it when grabbing the customers.

Observers on subscription events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991195/2205881 and [Adding a custom field to Magento's subscription module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155784/adding-a-custom-field-to-magentos-subscribtion-module)

Extending the v2 API: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/