# Can't set custom value in Observer

Tags: magento

I have a custom column named 'is_synchronized' in my newsletter_subcriber table.
It's a tinyint field that's changed to 1 when the administrator synchronizes subscribers to an external application.

I use the event 'newsletter_subscriber_save_before' to change the value back to 0 if a customer/guest unsubscribes.

I can read the information of the subscriber, but I can't change the value of 'is_synchronized'.
Please see the following code in my observer

```
$subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();

if($subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == '3'):

    $sub = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->load(intval($subscriber->getSubscriberId()));
    $sub->setIsSynchronized(0);
    try{
        $sub->save();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());        
    }
endif;
```

Can anybody tell me why I can't update a subcriber? Is there a more suitable event? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento - no event for newsletter subscribe & unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835132/magento-no-event-for-newsletter-subscribe-unsubscribe)

In Observer.php:

```
public function subscriberSync(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{

    $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();

    if($subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == '3'){
        $subscriber->setIsSynchronized(0);
    }

}
```

Your above code should not work because your saving with-in the observer, then the data will be overwritten (or an infinite loop).